# How to use socket like InetAddress

Tags: android, sockets

I'm android developer in korea. currently, I have made a project about socket.
but, I have some problem so I entered this site.
look!

```
 class PingCheckThread implements Runnable{

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    try {
                        if(device != null){
                            for(int i = 0; i < device.size(); i++){
                                String info = (String) device.get(i);
                                int first = info.indexOf(":");
                                int last = info.lastIndexOf(":");
                                String ip = info.substring(first, last);
                                InetAddress targetIp = 
Inet4Address.getByAddress(ip.getBytes()); ///< error!!

                                if(targetIp.isReachable(60000)){
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Connection Ok");
                                }else{
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Connection Fail");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Log>

```
08-26 11:27:34.124: W/dalvikvm(3612): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2c43b930)
08-26 11:27:35.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3612): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-216
08-26 11:27:35.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3612): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 11:27:35.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3612):  at com.skb.sportscompanion.tv.SportsCompanionTV$PingCheckThread.run(SportsCompanionTV.java:206)
08-26 11:27:35.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3612):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Why the inetAddress have the nullpointerexception? It appearienced InetAddress.getByName, InetAddress.geyByAddress. I want to know this error.
I already wrote uses-permission.
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

Comment: You haven't stated which is line 206, so your question isn't answerable, but you're really expected to be able to sort out NullPointerExceptions in your own code by yourself.

Comment: line 206 is Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());. why It have error?

Comment: No idea, but the real question is what was the exception that was caught at that point? Can't you log the entire exception? It may not even have a message.